# Suggested recommendation/off-site resource close vote reason

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

As we already had a number of questions that ask for recommendations or some off-site resources which are deemed as [being off-topic](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for our site, I'd like to suggest the addition of a predefined off-topic close vote reason for this type of questions.

The wording could be similar to existing reasons on other sites like Startups SE or Stack Overflow:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Computer Graphics as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe your problem or need and the steps, if any, you've taken to solve it.

What do you think about this? I'd like to have opinions from the community on whether or not to add such a reason and - if so - what the exact wording should be.

Comment: As a side note: We can create up to three custom close reasons and did not use any of them yet.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear if anyone has another reason instead of "they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam". Although that does seem to be the main reason for such questions being off topic, it also invites people to say "but that won't apply to *my* question".

Comment: Having said that, if no one suggests an alternative I'm perfectly happy with the suggested wording.

Comment: This reason is fine by me.

Comment: Do questions asking for a specific resource also fall into that cathegory? For example: _"What is the original source of the rendering equation?"_. As any science field, there are seminal publications and it seems to me asking for them would be appropriate.

Comment: @JulienGuertault You can see discussion of this at [Are requests for reputable sources on topic?](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/211/are-requests-for-reputable-sources-on-topic)